# How to correctly build an object from known keys that may or may not have data in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, handlebars.js, conditional-statements

I want to create an object where although I know the keys I don't actually want them in the object unless they have a value greater than zero.

Here's what I have, which works, I just want to know if this is the most elegant way to do this.

```
var tabs = {};

if(shot.attachments_count !== 0) {
    tabs.attachments = shot.attachments_count;
}

if(shot.buckets_count !== 0) {
    tabs.buckets = shot.buckets_count;
}

if(shot.comments_count !== 0) {
    tabs.comments = shot.comments_count;
}

if(shot.likes_count !== 0) {
    tabs.likes = shot.likes_count;
}

if(shot.rebounds_count !== 0) {
    tabs.rebounds = shot.rebounds_count;
}
```

UPDATE

Okay so here's what I have gone with:

```
var tabs = {},
    keys = [
        'attachments',
        'buckets',
        'comments',
        'likes',
        'rebounds'
    ];

keys.forEach(function(i) {

   if(shot[i + '_count'] > 0) {
       tabs[i] = shot[i + '_count'];
   }

});
```

I have to use an array as I do know the keys but also because I am working with the dribbble api and there are many more properties in shot, so I cannot iterate through everything as I only want the above in my object.

I am also using handlebars, so I am constructing an object to loop through the keys are my handlebars items and the shot.*_count are the dribbble api values.

I hope that explains better what I am doing, and thanks for your help

Comment: Why don't you want `attachments: 0` in your object? (And so on) There's a big difference between `0` and the absense of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate the keys and add them to `tabs`, only if they satisfy the condition, like this

```
var tabs = {};
Object.keys(shot).forEach(function(currentProperty) {
  // Check if the value corresponding to current property is greater than 0
  if (shot[currentProperty] > 0) {
    tabs[currentProperty.replace('_count', '')] = shot[currentProperty];
  }
});
```

As suggested by T.J.Crowder, if the list of keys is known before hand, you can make them an array and iterate only them, like this

```
var keys = ['attachments_count', 'buckets_count' ... ];
keys.forEach(...);
```

This will be better because, you will not accidentally copy other unwanted  properties from `shot`, if there are any.

Comment: `>` is different from `!==` :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah yes. I read only the question, which says `unless they have a value greater than zero`

Comment: :-) With "counts" it probably doesn't matter. Might also be worth using `["attachment_count", ...].forEach` in case `shot` has things in it that shouldn't be copied. Good answer regardless.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yup, I included the static list of keys way as well. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a counter we're assuming they'll always have a numeric value and it's going to be `>=0`. Also you always want to strip out `__count` from the key. Then you can do this:

```
var tabs = {};
for(key in shot){
  if(!shot[key]){
    continue;
  }
  tabs[key.substr(0, key.length - 6)] = shot[key];
}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's a counter though, I assumed it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
var shotKeys = Object.keys(shot);
var tabKeys = [];
var tab = {};

for (var i = 0; i < shotKeys.length; i++) { 
  tabKeys.push(shotKeys[i].split('_')[0]); 
  if (shot[shotKeys[i]] > 0) { 
    tab[tabKeys[i]] = shot[shotKeys[i]]; 
  }
}
```